# Background music either stops or always restarts

Tags: android

I searched a lot about background music and so far haven't found anything that actually worked as I wanted. Most examples won't stop the app's background music if you press the HOME key.

Then i found this example: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

I re-arranged the code to my needs, I only need music that flows through all the activities, even if you go back to a previous activity and stops once you press the HOME button.

This is my code:

```
public class MusicManager {
private static final String TAG = "MusicManager";

private static MediaPlayer mp;

private static int currentMusic = 0;

public static void start(Context context, int music) {
    start(context, music, false);
    }

public static void start(Context context, int music, boolean force) {

    if (!force && currentMusic > 0) {
        // already playing some music and not forced to change
        return;
    }

    currentMusic = 1;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, music);
    if (mp != null) {
        if (!mp.isPlaying()) {

            mp.setVolume(100, 100);
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        }
    }

}

public static void pause() {

    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
    }
}

public static void release() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Releasing media players");
    try {
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            }
            mp.release();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Then I use for each activity I want the music to keep playing in:

```
private static boolean continueMusic = true // field boolean

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!continueMusic) {
        MusicManager.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    continueMusic = false;
    MusicManager.start(this, R.raw.musica);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e){
    if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        continueMusic = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, with this code my music only works in the Main activity (notice I don't call onKeyDown in mainactivity as explained in the link I gave), if I remove the following code from the MusicManager class:

```
if (!force && currentMusic > 0) {
        // already playing some music and not forced to change
        return;
    }
```

The music is restarted in every activity. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this, and I can't test it at the moment.
But I think the problem is with your context. Try giving the music player an application context like this:

```
context.getApplicationContext();
```